# I'm trying to read sensor data through serial communication but when I try to read it just kept on runnin in python but it doesn't display any value

Tags: python-3.x, readline, pyserial

I have light detector sensors connected to a data acquisition box and it is connected to my laptop via RS232 usb cable. I have stabilized serial communication to that port in python. But when I try to read the data it just keeps on running and it doesn't display any value. I have tried this same think in MATALB and it works properly, so I know that port and sensors are working fine. I am just not able to read the data in python. I have three ways(shown below in python code) but nothing works. Please help me.

Here is my python code:

```py
import serial
from serial import Serial

s = serial.Serial('COM3')  # open serial port
print(ser.name)         

# Set the serial port to desired COM 
s = serial.Serial(port = 'COM3', bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, baudrate = 9600, stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

# Read the data(method 1)
while 1:
    while (s.inWaiting() > 0):
        try:
            inc = s.readline().strip()
            print(inc)
         
# Read the data(method 2)        
data = str(s.read(size = 1))
print(data)

# Read all the data(method 3)
while i <10:
    b = s.readlines(100) # reading all the lines
```

Comment: Does the device output a newline?  A quick look at https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html suggests you want `s.read`.

Comment: I am not sure. How do I even check that. When I was doing it in matlab it gave values with a space but in same line. I have tried s.read as well but it doesn't return any value. It just keeps on running(executing) the code but doesn't display any value.

Comment: I ran the code and it pauses at print(inc) line. It doesn't move to other line not even to timeoutexception. I think the code so far reads the port but I am missing a code line which extracts the data from different channels of DAQ. In matlab I use this code to read the data: MATLAB Code:
fwrite(s,strcat('#010',hex2dec('0D')));
out1 = fgetl(s)
out1 = out1(2:end);
out1 = str2num(out1);
if(out1 < 0)
    out1 = 0;
else
end  Output: 131.2500  121.8750

Answer (score 1):

> in matlab it gave values with a space but in same line

That indicates there are no newline characters sent by the device.

I've never used your device or the Python serial module.  But from the docs, this is what I would do:

```
from time import sleep

while s.is_open():
    n = s.in_waiting()
    if n == 0:
        print "no data"
        sleep(1)
        continue
    try:
        inc = s.read(n)
        print(inc)
    catch serial.SerialException as oops:
        print(oops)
    catch serial.SerialTimeoutException as oops:
        print(oops)
print("serial port closed")
```

This gives you feedback for each condition: port open/closed, data ready/not, and the data, if any. From there you can figure out what to do.

The [documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) says `inWaiting` is deprecated, so I used `in_waiting`.

I wouldn't be surprised if the problem lies in configuring the serial port in the first place.  Serial ports are tricky like that.

Comment: I ran the code and it pauses at print(inc) line. It doesn't move to other line not even to timeoutexception. I think the code so far reads the port but I am missing a code line which extracts the data from differnet channels of data acqusition box. In matlab after setting the serial port I use this code to read the data: MATLAB Code: % Sensor 1 data
fwrite(s,strcat('#010',hex2dec('0D')));
out1 = fgetl(s)
out1 = out1(2:end);
out1 = str2num(out1);
out1 = 9375*out1-37500+93.75 % convert mA to lux

if(out1 < 0)
    out1 = 0;
else
    
end

Comment: I think by "pauses" you mean it stops before `print(inc)`, which would mean the read is blocking.  I don't know Matlab, but `fwrite(s,strcat('#010',hex2dec('0D')));` looks like you're *writing* to the device first, specifically the string "#010\r", where I'm using "\r" to mean a carriage return, which, in hex, is `0D`.  If so, you may need a similar `s.write` in your Python before the `read` statement.